# APK Expansion Files

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I want to test if APK expansion file is downloading and working correctly. Can I publish my app but make it visible only for myself, to test installing and APK expansion file working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [reference](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing), in "Testing file downloads":
Click the Save button. Do not click Publish. This saves the application as a draft, such that your application is not published for Google Play users, but the expansion files are available for you to test the download process.